# Loop through an array of data and print an 'incrementing' letter

Tags: php

I need to loop through an array of data and print an 'incrementing' letter for each array value. I know I can do this:

```
$array = array(11, 33, 44, 98, 1, 3, 2, 9, 66, 21, 45); // array to loop through
$letters = array('a', 'b', 'c', ...); // array of letters to access
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    echo $letters[$i++] . " - $value";
}
```

It seems that there should be a better way than having to create an alphabet array. Any suggestions?

Note - My loop will never get through the entire alphabet, so I'm not concerned about running out of letters.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. One thing it seems I didn't make very clear: I'm not looping through the letters, I'm looping through a different array of data. I just need incrementing letters as I go through that data. I'm just noting this in explanation for anyone visiting in the future. You've all provided me with the answers I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Scott, this comment should really be folded into the original question as an update, where it will be more prominent.

Comment: @George: I thought it was pretty clear from the code sample I provided and the original description. Obviously I was wrong :) I've edited the question a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: I see now that my question title was very misleading. I think the text of the question described what I wanted, but the title described a different problem - the one everyone answered. I've changed the title to reflect my real question.

Comment: I know what you mean, but we need to work with the human brain's capabilities and all that jazz.  I missed the `$array` in the `foreach` on my first read.  Then, there was the question of whether it's a typo or not.  And, as you mention, the title was a bit different than the description.  Either way, my point was simply to place that comment in the body of the question, as it is easy to overlook in the comments section.  If it's important enough to the question, might as well edit and not worry about changing the question.  Or just add it as an addendum, without rewording the original.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$letters = range('a','z');
```

Answer (score 23):

Use the [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```
$letters = range('a', 'z');
print_r($letters);
```

You can also use `foreach` loop to take on each letter individually:

```
foreach($letters as $letter) {
    echo $letter . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I foresee a Populist badge in your future

Comment: You're welcome :) I accepted the other answer because your loop is not appropriate for my question.

Comment: Probably `foreach($letters as $theLetter) {` is slightly simpler to use, unless you need the key for any reason.

Comment: @Peter: perhaps, but I'm actually looping through an entirely different array - not the letters array.

Comment: @Scott - I see what you mean. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: haha sorry dude...but anyways, you only beat me by about 20 seconds..and actually i woulda gotten it in first but i got hit with the I'm a human! captcha thing when I first hit submit! Cheer up, I upvoted you :P

Comment: @crayon I don't think that's the issue.  Rather, his answer was a bit more developed.  (Granted, just a small bit more.)  I dunno if the OP realizes, but the `foreach` loop originally provided in the answer would give him a counter in `$key` that he wouldn't need to increment manually, since the the loop was processing a numeric array.

Comment: Can one change the alphabet that range() uses (other than English)? Is this set in the server's PHP settings? Could I use one language set in the server settings and a different alphabet when calling the function? That would be cool.

Answer (score 8):

Just as a demonstration (I know you've already accepted an answer), but it's sometimes useful to know that you can also increment character variables:

```
$var = 'a';
do {
   echo $var++.'<br />';
} while ($var != 'aa');
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize you already accepted and answer, but I believe this is what you're looking for:

Simple use of the increment operator:

```
<?php
$array = array("cat","car","far","tar","tag");

  // No need for an array, just set $letter to "a", then increment it.
$letter = "a";

foreach($array as $value) {
      // Print your letter, then increment it.
    echo $letter++ . " - $value\n";
}
?>
```

[Look at it live.](http://codepad.org/TMFJ6UJ9)

The big *advantage* of using this method over creating an array is that **you don't need to worry about running out of letters**, since you just move into double letters: [like this](http://codepad.org/kCHalXFQ).

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($counter = ord('a'); $counter <= ord('z'); $counter += 1) {
    echo chr($counter) . " - $counter";
}
```

Comment: Ewww.  There are far cleaner ways than to loop between two magic-looking numbers.

Comment: +1 for the only answer so far that doesn't require a throwaway array of letters.

Comment: Better.  The range('a', 'z') solutions still feel more elegant, but this does at least keep from creating the extra array.  The echo needs changing, though, as $value was being set by the foreach loop -- and the numbers need to be echoed too somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean to have something that looked like this?

```
foreach(range('a','z') as $value)
{
  echo $value . ","
}
```

Comment: Crayon's mention of the range function indicated a better way.  Code example updated to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to have an iterator if you make use of the `$key => $value` functionality of a foreach loop:

```
$letters = range('a', 'z');

foreach($letters as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . '=>' . $value;
}
```

You could even go as far as to simply do:

```
foreach(range('a', 'z') as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . '=>' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add for fun...

```
$array = array(11, 33, 44, 98, 1, 3, 2, 9, 66, 21, 45);
$new_array = array_combine(array_slice(range('a','z'),0,count($array)),$array);
    foreach($new_array as $k=>$v){
        echo "$k - $v";
    }
```