# PHP change the value of an array to character

Tags: php, arrays

```
 $a = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)

$result = Array(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
```

I want to change $a to $result to result I tried every way I know but it's hard to find the answer Is there any way?
Also, the $a array can grow and shrink.

```
1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C, 4 = D, 5 = E, 6 = F etc...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! "I tried every way I know" -- could you share your attempts? Do you know about [`chr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) and `foreach` or `map`?

Comment: yes I need array_map and foreach!

Comment: Maybe some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36423545/2943403

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410970/2943403  and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47322831/2943403

Comment: I am confused.  Is the desired result: `[0 => 'A', 1 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D']` or `[1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'C', 4 => 'D']`?  Are the input values always in order? always ascending? always less than 27? (what happens if you run out of alphabetical letters? do you use double lettering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have simply achieved using the [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map) and the [chr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) functions as:

I hope this is what you're looking for. No matter in which sequence the numbers are, it'll be taken care of:

```
<?php

$a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$result = array_map(function ($v) {
    return chr(64 + $v);
}, $a);

print_r($result);

?>
```

You can achieve the same using a `foreach` and the `chr` function as:

```
<?php

$a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$result = [];

foreach($a as $v) {
    $result[] = chr(64 + $v);
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

or you could simply use the `chr` function when using the array value as:

```
echo chr(64 + $a[$index]);
```

---

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
```

and for the input: `$a = [2, 3, 1, 4];` result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => B
    [1] => C
    [2] => A
    [3] => D
)
```

Comment: Syntax error in array_map...

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? BTW I have updated the answer

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.3...!

Comment: Can I see the code again before the update?

Comment: There is a server with an updated PHP version, and we will check it again there

Comment: @You can see the edit history here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68585461/revisions, though you should use the updated answer .

Comment: 1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C, 4 = D, 5 = E, 6 = F, 7 = G, 8 = H1, 9 = H2 end!!  I think you should know

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: This task can be achieved without making any iterated function calls.  See if you can figure out this technique @OMi

Comment: Referring to elsewhere: Adding an answer after a question is closed has a "grace period". It is not meant to be exploited, but it is not considered a bug as far as I know.

Comment: @Yunnosch, actually you're right. I realized later, sir. :)